# Deploying C# application that uses Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, deployment, crystal-reports

I'm developing a .net 2.0 C# program with VS2005 that prints Crystal Reports document. The program is to be deployed at client computer just to take raw rpt file and print, no design required.

I use the following code:

```
    ReportDocument crrpt = new ReportDocument();
    crrpt.Load(pathtorptfile);

    crrpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = settings.Print_printer;
    crrpt.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Portrait;
    crrpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

On the machine with full CR XI R2 developer with designer installed, it managed to send job prints to printer.

What are the steps to deploy or create installer for this program so it can install and run on the client computer? If possible at minimal without the need to install the full CR. Also, does the client need the license to read and print?

Appreciate guide or link for this. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of problem while using Crystal Reports and there are few things you should be aware.

- You don't have to install Crystal in your client's computer. But it mut be installed in the server where it is running.
- What you probably are facing is CR and server compatibility.
- Also double check whether is it running 64 or 32 bits. This is very important.

Note: I am assuming you are using Windows as a server.
Please check out this table, with all versions and compatibilities: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com&pageId=56787567